# Полная автоматизация установки web-сервера на Debian

Tags: debian, bash, linux

Команда которой я ставлю веб сервер:

```
aptitude update && aptitude upgrade && \
 aptitude install apache2-mpm-itk nginx php5 libapache2-mod-php5 \
 mysql-server mysql-client php5-mysql phpmyadmin
```

Во время установки требуется несколько подтверждений и вводов пароля:

1. Подтверждение (Y/N) Нужно Y
2. Нужно ввести `MySQL Root PASS`
3. Еще раз ввести `MySQL Root PASS`
4. Появляется экран на котором стрелками выбор установленного веб-сервера ( 1 - `Apache`, 2 - `lighttpd`). Нужно 1
5. Подтверждение авто настройки `phpmyadmin` (Нужно Yes)
6. `Pass of database admin user`
7. `Pass of database admin user - Retype`
8. `Pass of database admin user - Retype`

Как это автоматизировать с помощью `Bash` скрипта. Чтобы скрипт сам все подтвердил и ввел?

Comment: @Flasko, Это вопрос на форум [РутКод](http://admin.hashcode.ru/).

в debian есть сценарии автоматической установки.

Comment: а еще есть системы типа [puppet][1]


  [1]: https://puppetlabs.com/

Comment: "в debian есть сценарии автоматической установки." можно поподробнее?

А просто с помощью Bash никак?

Comment: Почитайте о команде `expect`.

Comment: да нельзя делать aptitude upgrade автоматом, т.е. можно, но последствия не предсказуемы. мало ли что оно спросит.

Answer (score 5):

1. утвердительные ответы на вопросы да/нет можно получить, передав опцию `-y`:

   ```
   $ sudo aptitude -y ...
   $ sudo apt-get -y ...
   ```
2. конфигурационные опции можно задать до установки пакетов. посмотреть опции, например, для пакета *mysql-server-5.5* (естественно, уже после установки):

   ```
   $ sudo debconf-show mysql-server-5.5
   * mysql-server/root_password_again: (password omitted)
   * mysql-server/root_password: (password omitted)
     mysql-server-5.5/postrm_remove_databases: false
     mysql-server/password_mismatch:
     mysql-server-5.5/start_on_boot: true
     mysql-server-5.5/nis_warning:
     mysql-server/no_upgrade_when_using_ndb:
     mysql-server-5.5/really_downgrade: false
     mysql-server/error_setting_password:
   ```

   конфигурационные опции для всех установленных пакетов можно посмотреть программой `debconf-get-selections` из пакета `debconf-utils`.

   установить, например, пароль и подтверждение для пакета `mysql-server-5.5` можно так:

   ```
   $ echo 'mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password password ваш_пароль' | sudo debconf-set-selections
   $ echo 'mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password_again password ваш_пароль' | sudo debconf-set-selections
   ```
3. полностью отключить всякую интерактивность при выполнении `aptitude`, `apt-get`, `apt`, `dpkg` и т.п., можно с помощью переменной окружения `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` со значением `noninteractive`:

   ```
   $ sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive aptitude install ...
   ```