# Автоматическое подтверждение команд

Tags: bash

Добрый вечер.

Как реализовать автоматическое подтверждение, допустим устанавливая mysql-server, где нужно вписывать пароль, чтобы пароль автоматически вводился и автоматически всё подтверждалось?

UPD: установка проходит через apt-get install ... (... - название).

Comment: А зачем? Это существенное изменение для системы, которое обычно делается один раз.

Comment: Я пишу скрипт, для подготовки VDS к работе, где всё устанавливается самое нужное.

Comment: как именно вы устанавливаете mysql-server?

Comment: Допишите эту деталь в вопрос. И надеюсь, вы знаете, что это велосипед. Host provisioning это очень популярная задача с кучей готовых решений.

Comment: apt-get install mysql-server

Comment: Извините. Нашёл ответ - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/211230/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-web-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-debian?rq=1