# DOCKER Во время установки пакета необходимо ввести дополнительные данные

Tags: docker

Всем привет.
Сейчас я пишу докерфайл для базы, и у меня возникла проблема.
Во время билда, 1-у из пакетов, необходимо ввести локацию, в моё случае это "8", 
а после этого еще и часовой пояс то же в виде числового значения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой текущий конфигурационный файл:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
COPY app /app

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl

RUN curl -L https://tarantool.io/tmiDJVT/release/2.8/installer.sh | bash
RUN apt-get -y install tarantool

RUN apt install git
RUN apt install cmake
RUN apt install make
RUN apt install gcc

RUN tarantoolctl rocks install vshard

ENTRYPOINT ["tarantool app/"]
CMD storage.lua 8a274925-a26d-47fc-9e1b-af88ce939412
```

Я не знаю докер, сейчас изучать его очень долго, а решение нужно срочно. Кто-нибуть знает решение?

Comment: Посмотреть, как сам тарантул делает себе докеры https://github.com/tarantool/docker

Comment: `ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` наверное https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466255

Comment: [примерно дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446359/178576)

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install tarantool -y
```

Спасибо @andreyma